# Why "Lagrange's' MVT?

Tags: real-analysis, math-history

Apparently, in English, we often speak of "Lagrange's" Mean Value Theorem. Why? What's the historical background? Isn't that theorem rather attributed to Cauchy or Rolle?

Of course, I noticed, we often use Cauchy for the "stronger MVT", 
$$ \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)} = \frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)} $$ but still I don't get how Lagrange's name got involved.

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this:

http://abesenyei.web.elte.hu/publications/meanvalue.pdf

could be helppful.

Comment: Nice slides! But a link-only answer is not ideal.